# Form View hide button via CSS

Tags: css, xml, odoo, odoo-12

On Form View i want to hide a button if Customer `partner_id` is False, i tried `t-if` with no luck i tied `attrs` but also didnt work.

Check status of Customer `partner_id`:

[image]

I want to hide the button Send Message:

[image]

Any solution?

I tried to run CSS to hide the button

My Code:

```
<field name="name" attrs="{'invisible': [('partner_id', '=', False)]}">
      <style>
        .o_chatter_button_new_message {
                display: none !important;
        }
      </style>
      </field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in [FormRenderer](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#views) and to hide or show the button when the value of `partner_id` changes you can create a new many2one widget by extending `FieldMany2One` and changing the visibility state of the button depending on the value of `partner_id`.

In the following example, the `Send Message button` will be hidden if the `partner_id` is defined when the form view is loaded or when the value of `partner_id` is set to false. The button should be visible when the value of the partner is set (onchange event).

```
odoo.define('stack_overflow.chatter_button_new_message', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var FormRenderer = require('web.FormRenderer');

    FormRenderer.include({

        autofocus: function () {
            var self = this;
            if(self.state.model === 'project.task' && self.state.data.partner_id===false){
                var node = window.$('button.o_chatter_button_new_message');
                node.hide();
            }
            return this._super();
        },
    });

    var relational_fields = require('web.relational_fields');

    var FieldMany2One = relational_fields.FieldMany2One.extend({

        _onFieldChanged: function (event) {
            var node = window.$('button.o_chatter_button_new_message');
            if (event.data.changes[event.target.name]===false) {
                node.hide();
            } else {
                node.show();
            }

            this._super(event);
        },
    });

    fieldRegistry.add('hideSendMsg', FieldMany2One);
});
```

You should add the js file in an [asset bundle](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#adding-files-in-an-asset-bundle).

To use the widget defined above you will need to set the widget attribute of the `partner_id` field to `hideSendMsg` in the XML definition.

```
<record id="view_task_form2_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">view.task.form2.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">project.task</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="project.view_task_form2"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="partner_id" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="widget">hideSendMsg</attribute>
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

=============================================================

**My Solution:** @Fotic

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        document.onload = check_status();
        document.onchange = check_status();
        function check_status() {
            if (document.getElementById("o_field_input_103")){
                var hasCSSClass = document.getElementById("o_field_input_103")
            }
            if (hasCSSClass){
              if ( hasCSSClass.classList.contains("o_field_empty") || hasCSSClass.classList.contains("o_input")) {
                  $(".o_chatter_button_new_message").show();
                  console.log("1111111111");
              } else{
                  $(".o_chatter_button_new_message").hide();
                  console.log("2222222222");
              }
            }
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: First of thaks for the effort.. can i run this code inside the form view? also i want to only check if `res.partner` field is empty... also what is `FormRenderer` becuase im too nobbie on Odoo?

Comment: You need to check if `partner_id` is equal to `false` then hide the button after the form view has loaded. The renderer job is representing the data being viewed in a DOM element. I edited my answer to add a link to the documentation of Odoo 12 views, Read the section about views and you will understand how it works. Add the model and the view you used and I will update my example above.

Comment: hello, the view i want put it is: `project.task.form` external_id: `project.view_task_form2` model: `project.task`. i whould be glad if you have time to help me ferver with this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, but i dont have access to back-end so i cant make it as an addon, but anyway i found solution, i dont think is perfect but is does the job. I will also accept your answer and edit write my solution for everyone else if he instrest.

Answer (score 0):

It can not be possible with the approach you did.
The **Send message** button is dynamically rendered and it's defined in the **Qweb** template.

You can find the **Button** Code here,[Click Here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/mail/static/src/xml/chatter.xml#L96)

**Solution**: To hide the button you can do it from the js where the button renders and passed value[with check the partner_id is False] and added the condition on the button itself.

Thanks